# can beanutil get the property of one field with its native type

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

Hi:
I am using BeanUtil to get the properties of some bean,then put them to map.
However I found that the `getProperty()` can only return the string value,I wonder if it can return the native(original) type?

For example:

### Bean:

```
public class Entity {
 private String  name;
 private int   age;
 private List<Date> childs = new ArrayList<Date>();

 public Entity(String name, int age, List<Date> childs) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.childs = childs;
 }

 public static Entity newInstance() {
  List<Date> list = new ArrayList<Date>();
  list.add(new Date());
  list.add(new Date());
  return new Entity("Beanutil", 23, list);
 }
 //the getter and setter for all the fields
}
```

---

```
Then I want to get some field property of it,and I do not exactly know which fields are requried,so I use it this way:

public class BeanUtilMain {
 public static void main(String[] args){
  String[] requestPro={"name","childs"}; //this field is specified by clien
  Map<String, Object> map=new HashMap<String, Object>();
  Entity en=Entity.newInstance();
  for(String p:requestPro){
   map.put(p, BeanUtils.getProperty(en, p));
  }
  System.out.println(map);
 }
}
```

Then the map is:

```
{name=beanutil, childs=Wed Dec 01 12:24:37 CST 2010}
```

The type of "childs" field is java.util.List,but in the example, it is converted to java.lang.String.

I have to hold the orignal type of the fields in the map.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`PropertyUtils.getProperty(Object, String)`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.0/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#getProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) to accomplish exactly this.  It returns the value of the field with no type conversion.